# Error: Invalid Adapter: asyncstorage, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, pouchdb

I updated my expo version from 47 to 49 and I get this error after execution.

```
Error: Invalid Adapter: asyncstorage, js engine: hermes
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in createErrorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in
at node_modules@react-native\js-polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.applyWithGuard
at node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:null in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.1.137:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in metroRequire
at http://192.168.1.137:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global
```

## The code :

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-react-native';
import PouchAuth from 'pouchdb-authentication';
import PouchAsyncStorage from 'pouchdb-adapter-asyncstorage';
import { storeData } from './storageManager';

PouchDB.plugin(PouchAuth);
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-upsert'));
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));

PouchDB.plugin(PouchAsyncStorage);

let LocalDatabase = new PouchDB('db_name', {
adapter: 'asyncstorage',
});
```

Somebody help me to resolve this error

Comment: The adapter has been abandoned. https://github.com/seigel/pouchdb-react-native/blob/master/README.md